# Debug on windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I can't debug my windows phone 7 project.while windows phone emulator is starting, the code stop on  **System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();**

How can i debug my project?

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        **System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();**
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the exception message. This is likely to be an exception caused by navigation issue.

Comment: Try using the Watch Window to see what the value of e.Message is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. the problem occur because of phone gps while determine the current location.Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

How about catching your exceptions? it might give you a clue on what exactly is throwing you the exception.[exceptions developers guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in Try-Catch Block. I was also facing such problem, but then handled by Exception Handling Method.

```
try
 {

   // your code

 }

catch (Exception ex)
 {

   throw (ex);
 }
```